# What extensions can index files have?

Tags: php, html, asp.net, apache, jsp

Creating a script to identify index files for a list of domains, can an index file have extensions other than “html” “htm” “php” “asp” “aspx” “jsp”?

Comment: Yes it can have.

Comment: How are you intending to identify them?  An index file may not exist at all for a lot of sites.

Comment: It can have _any_ extension, or none at all. What files to scan a directory for to find a default document to display, is a matter of _configuration_ of the web server.

Comment: @NigelRen it would have been a simple curl command to h**ps://domain.com/index.php etc. But i supposed if there was no index file, this would be insufficient. Identifying a 200 ok response with content that is different to a default initial webserver setup landing page would be better.

Comment: If you just make a cURL request to the root of the domain e.g. `https://www.example.com/` that will download the default content for that site, regardless of whether there's a specific index file or not. It's not really clear what you're trying to do - why do you need to identify index files, as such? As mentioned above, many sites don't really have that concept anyway